# PHP Pagination Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search that I am trying to have pagination with. I found a cool php script, [at PHPEasyStep](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html) (Yeah, I'm new at PHP, and programming.) I implemented it, and it worked to display pagination and to go forward a page( from page 1 to page 2), but when you go back from  page 2 to page 1, the search query is gone and then displays every single database entry (but paginated). The search query must be getting lost somewhere?

[image: What's Happening?]

The Code ( When I pasted this is got compacted so I've done my best to indent but I'm SUPER sorry if any is still hard to read. If its too hard to read its mostly on the website I got it from in better indentation...there is a link above!)

```
<?php
     $q = mysql_real_escape_string(ucfirst(trim($_GET['searchquery'])));
?>
 <?php

  REQUIRE('config.php');

  $tbl_name="companies";

  $adjacents = 3;


  $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE company_name LIKE '%$q%' OR      company_description LIKE '%$q%' OR cat1 LIKE '%$q' OR cat2 LIKE '%$q' OR cat3 LIKE '%$q' OR company_phone LIKE '%$q'";

  $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
  $total_pages = $total_pages[num];


  $targetpage = "search.php";
  $limit = 10;                              
  $page = $_GET['page'];
  if($page){
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; 
  }         
  else{
    $start = 0;                             
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE company_name LIKE '%$q%' OR company_description LIKE '%$q%' OR cat1 LIKE '%$q' OR cat2 LIKE '%$q' OR cat3 LIKE '%$q' OR company_phone LIKE '%$q' ORDER by company_name LIMIT $start, $limit";

  $result = mysql_query($sql);


  if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                    
  $prev = $page - 1;                            
  $next = $page + 1;                            
  $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);        
  $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                        

  $pagination = "";
  if($lastpage > 1)
  { 
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev+searchquery=$q\">� previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">� previous</span>"; 

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter+searchquery=$q\">$counter</a>";                  
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter+searchquery=$q\">$counter</a>";                  
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1+searchquery=$q\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage+searchquery=$q\">$lastpage</a>";        
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1+searchquery=$q\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2+searchquery=$q\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter+searchquery=$q\">$counter</a>";                  
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1+searchquery=$q\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage+searchquery=$q\">$lastpage</a>";        
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1+searchquery=$q\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2+searchquery=$q\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter+searchquery=$q\">$counter</a>";                  
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next+searchquery=$q\">next �</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next �</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
?>
```

If you need any more code, I can quickly provide! Thanks for any and all help!

Oh I forgot to say that I tried to fix this by adding +searchquery=$q to the end of all the pagination urls so thats why that is there.

Comment: Could you post two links? The *working* link to page 2 when you are on page one; and the *faulty* link back to page 1 when you've opened page 2 from the previous link. What matters here is just the query string part, so you can obscure the real domain and path as e.g. `site.com/page.php?this=part&matters=here`

Comment: ok so when you go to page 2 when you are on page 1 the url ends with mysite.com/search.php?page=2+searchquery=Something and when you've opened page 2 from the previous link and go to page 1 it is mysite.com/search.php?page=1+searchquery=    . It's just blank.

Comment: Have you tried `&searchquery=$q`? An ampersand is what separates GET arguments, not a plus sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev+searchquery=$q\">� previous</a>";
```

should be:

```
if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev&searchquery=$q\">� previous</a>";
```

Comment: I suggested the same in my comment on the main post, but this doesn't actually seem to make sense. It works fine for going to the next page, which has the same problem (+ instead of &), but not for going back a page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `+searchquery=$q` with `&searchquery=$q`